# How to create a route with get parameter in v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have some routes that besides needing two different ids, some of them need to be forwarded as get parameter, how to do this in the current version of React Router Dom v6?

**PATHS:**

```
path='/shorts/:userShortId?&ab_channel=*'
path='/watch?v=*&ab_channel=*'
```

**CODE:**

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter basename='/'>
      <GlobalStyle />

      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path='/login' element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route
          path='/shorts/:userShortId?&ab_channel=*'
          element={<HomePage />}
        />
        <Route path='/watch?v=*&ab_channel=*' element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path='/feed'>
          <Route path='subscriptions' element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path='library' element={<HomePage />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/channel/:userChannelId' element={<HomePage />}>
          <Route path='videos' element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path='playlists' element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path='community' element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path='channels' element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path='about' element={<HomePage />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='*' element={<NotFoundPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: `react-router-dom` only concerns itself with the *path* portion of a URL for route matching. Any queryString access should be done in a React component. Can you provide a code example for the `HomePage` component that is potentially reading these queryString params? Are you trying to assign values to specific params, or do you just need to read specific params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the tests I've been doing and by looking at the docs [example](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/search-params), It seems that you don't need to define the query parameters in the route definition. You only need the `path` and `path variables (:something)`. Then, inside of the component you can make use of react router `useSearchParams` hooks to retrieve the parameters from the URL.

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter basename="/">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<h1>Home</h1>} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<h1>Login</h1>} />
        <Route path="/shorts/:userShortId" element={<Shorts />} />
        <Route path="/watch" element={<h1>watch</h1>} />
        ...
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

And for instance, in the `Shorts` component you could have

```js
function Shorts() {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    const paramsAsObject = Object.fromEntries([...searchParams]);

    console.log(paramsAsObject);
  }, [searchParams]);

  return <h1>shorts</h1>;
}
```